# SwiftUI - Decoding a JSON returns blank screen

Tags: json, swift, api, swiftui, codable

I am trying to decode a JSON object from a remote API, Xcode doesn't raise any flags but the screen remains blank, I couldn't pinpoint where the error is coming from but if I have to take I guess, I think it's something to do with my parsing.
**What's going wrong here? everything seems at its place**

This is my ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

```
@State var results = UserProducts(status: Bool(), userProducts: [UserProduct]())

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(spacing: nil) {
            ForEach(0..<results.userProducts!.count) {
                res in
                VStack(){Text(verbatim: String(format: String(),((results.userProducts![res].id ?? "NA"))))}
            }.onAppear(perform: loadShelf)
        }         
    }
    Spacer()
}).background(Color(red: 250 / 255, green: 248 / 255, blue: 244 / 255))
}

func loadShelf(){
    
    guard let apiBaseURL = URL(string: "...") else {
        print("Base URL is invalid.")
        return
    }
    
    let request = URLRequest(url: apiBaseURL)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let data = data {
                do{
                    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserProducts.self, from: data)
                    self.results = decoded
                    print("decoded: \(decoded)")
                    //prints: UserProducts(status: nil, userProducts: nil, recommendedProducts: nil)
                }
                catch{
                    print("Fetching data failed: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This is my Structs:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - UserProducts
struct UserProducts: Codable {
    let status: Bool?
    let userProducts: [UserProduct]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case userProducts = "user_products"
    }
}

// MARK: - UserProduct
struct UserProduct: Codable {
    let id, userID, productID: Int?
    let routineTime, createdAt, updatedAt: String?
    let archived, volume: Int?
    let deletedAt, addedBy, weeklyRoutineOne, weeklyRoutineTwo: String?
    let product: Product?
    let user: User?
    let phaseOut, refill, empty, recommended: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case productID = "product_id"
        case routineTime = "routine_time"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case archived, volume
        case deletedAt = "deleted_at"
        case addedBy = "added_by"
        case weeklyRoutineOne = "weekly_routine_one"
        case weeklyRoutineTwo = "weekly_routine_two"
        case product, user
        case phaseOut = "phase_out"
        case refill, empty, recommended
    }
}

// MARK: - Product
struct Product: Codable {
    let productName, productDescription, productIngredients: String?
    let productPrice, volume: Int?
    let image, interference, activeIngredients, howToUse: String?
    let brandID, productTypeID: Int?
    let brand, type: Brand?
    let rating: JSONNull?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case productName = "product_name"
        case productDescription = "product_description"
        case productIngredients = "product_ingredients"
        case productPrice = "product_price"
        case volume, image, interference
        case activeIngredients = "active_ingredients"
        case howToUse = "how_to_use"
        case brandID = "brand_id"
        case productTypeID = "product_type_id"
        case brand, type, rating
    }
}

// MARK: - Brand
struct Brand: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name, createdAt, updatedAt, commission: String?
    let category: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case commission, category
    }
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let name, email: String?
    let image1, deviceToken: JSONNull?
    let account, followup: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, email, image1
        case deviceToken = "device_token"
        case account, followup
    }
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // No-op
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

Now this is the JSON model and how it's supposed to look:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "user_products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "product_id": 1,
      "routine_time": "",
      "created_at": "",
      "updated_at": "",
      "archived": 0,
      "volume": 1,
      "deleted_at": "",
      "added_by": "",
      "weekly_routine_one": "",
      "weekly_routine_two": "",
      "product": {
        "product_name": "",
        "product_description": "",
        "product_ingredients": "",
        "product_price": 1,
        "volume": 1,
        "image": "",
        "interference": "",
        "active_ingredients": "",
        "how_to_use": "",
        "brand_id": 1,
        "product_type_id": 1,
        "brand": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "",
          "created_at": "",
          "updated_at": "",
          "commission": ""
        },
        "type": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "",
          "created_at": "",
          "updated_at": "",
          "category": 1
        },
        "rating": null
      },
      "user": {
        "name": "",
        "email": "",
        "image1": null,
        "device_token": null,
        "account": false,
        "followup": false
      },
      "phase_out": 0,
      "refill": 0,
      "empty": 0,
      "recommended": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `I think it's something to do with my parsing` + `try?` => Don't use `try?`, do a property `do`/`try`/`catch`, you'll see...

Comment: Then, the answer is pretty straighforward if we read the error message, or analyse your Codable struct vs the JSON you show: `.decode([UserProducts].self,` => `.decode(UserProducts.self,`...

Comment: @Larme it is still a blank screen, nothing is showing

Comment: Check first if `self.results = response.first` is really called, that's checking your parsing. If yes, then your issue is not in your parsing anymore, but in the rendering part...

Comment: Yes, Xcode does not raise any flags, because runtime error handling is your responsibility. And you didn't handle runtime errors.

Comment: @Larme yes, it's not being called, it does not go into `DispatchQueue`

Comment: So you did write a do/try/catch instead of `try?` as I suggested, printed the error in case of the catch and read it? Also, did you changed the fact that your response seems to be an object, and not an array of object: `.decode([UserProducts].self` => `.decode(UserProducts.self,`? Because if that would be the case, I guess you changed later `self.results = response.first!` into `self.results = response`, else, I guess it wouldn't compile anymore...

Comment: @Larme actually I am putting  the .onAppear in the wrong place, moved it to the closing of ScrollView!

Comment: @Larme I tried what you recommended I wrapped it in a do..try..catch, the catch is not triggered but inside the do this is what get `UserProducts(status: nil, userProducts: nil, recommendedProducts: nil)` please check the updated code

Comment: Why are all your Codable struct properties optional? Could you print `String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` to be sure about the JSON you are receiving vs the JSON you pasted which I guess you're supposed (but maybe not the real one) to receive...

Comment: I am debugging and fixing, the only problem is with the array of products "user_products" it remained nil, the boolean status is getting through like it should

Answer (score 2):

You actually have two problems here.

1st, this is where your nils are coming from:

```
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
       try container.encodeNil()
    }
```

If you comment it out or make it do what you actually want it to do instead of what it's currently doing (making everything nil)... that'll bring us to problem #2

You'll have your data, but because it's all optionals, there's some unwrapping that needs to be done before it'll make much sense.